# Matlab: Applying a function to chunks of data

Tags: matlab, matrix, lambda, anonymous-function

I have a Matlab function that takes a matrix and a chunk_size as the input, reshapes it into chunks of chunk_size dimension.

For example, if I have the following matrix:

```
data=
 1     3
 2     5
 3    42
 4    35
 5    16
 6    48
 7     2
 8    22
 9    20
10    39
11    40
```

the function, using a chunk_size of 3 will output:

```
data(:,:,1) =
 1     3
 2     5
 3    42
data(:,:,2) =
 4    35
 5    16
 6    48
data(:,:,3) =
 7     2
 8    22
 9    20
```

The last rows of the original data are discarded because they do not fit completely into a chunk.

I would now be able to let the **user** to specify a function to apply to each slice of the 3D Matrix via a function parameter.
So, for example, if the user wants to apply a sum of the elements, he could use the sum function provided by matlab to obtain:

```
data(:,:,1) =
 6    50
data(:,:,2) =
15    99
data(:,:,3) =
24    44
```

At the same time, I want for example to allow the user to let him apply the sum function on the other dimension, to obtain:

```
data(:,:,1) =
 4
 7
45
data(:,:,2) =
39
21
54
data(:,:,3) =
 9
30
29
```

I feel all of this could be obtained somehow through anonymous functions or something like that, but i can't figure out how.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
chunk_size=3;
data= [1 3;2 5 ;3 42; 4 35; 5 16; 6 48; 7 2; 8 22; 9 20; 10 39; 11 40];
[m,n]=size(data); % m:row n:column
m_new=mod(m,chunk_size); % how many rows to clear

% process of clearing last (unwanted) rows
while m_new~=0
   data(m,:)=[];
   m=m-1;
   m_new=m_new-1;
end

% process of creating 3D matrix
a=1;
for i=1:3
   for j=1:chunk_size
    new_data(j,:,i)=data(a,:);
    a=a+1;
   end
end
    
% conversion to name of new_data to data
data=new_data;

% example of sum row elements 
sum(data(:,:,1))

% example of sum column elements 
sum(data(:,:,1),2)
```

output of this

> 6 50
>
> 4
>
> 7
>
> 45